# Android: ler dados JSON

Tags: android, json

Tenho um *url* que me dá os dados neste formato:

```
{"to": "DKK", "rate": 7.4417, "from": "EUR"}
```

Estou a tentar lê-los da seguinte forma:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject(site);
String to = (String)obj2.get("to");
Double rate = obj2.getDouble("rate");
```

**ERRO**:

> org.json.JSONException: No value for http://rate-exchange-1.appspot.com/currency?from=EUR&to=DKK
>   04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
>   04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
>   04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at com.converter.android.converter.ConvertActivity$Parse.doInBackground(ConvertActivity.java:1579)
>   04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at com.converter.android.converter.ConvertActivity$Parse.doInBackground(ConvertActivity.java:1547)
>   04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>   04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>   04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   04-22 23:06:56.114 19331-19991/com.converter.android.converter W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem que passar a resposta do site para jSon, não o a url. Para pegar a resposta use essa clase:

```
public class HttpConnections {
 //método get
public static String get(String urlString){
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resposta = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        resposta = buffer.toString();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (urlConnection != null){
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            reader.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return resposta;
}
}
```

Depois é só chamar passando sua url(tem que ser usado em outra Thread).

```
String resposta = HttpConnections.get(" http://rate-exchange-1.appspot.com/currency?from=EUR&to=DKK");
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resposta);
String to = obj.getString("to");
Double rate = obj.getDouble("rate");
String from = obj.getString("from");
```

Comment: Obrigada! Funcionou!

Answer (score 2):

Você está a tentar fazer *parse* do site. No entanto, você deveria fazer *parse* da resposta (dados) que esta URL te dá. Por exemplo"

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resposta);
String to = obj.getString("to");
```

Note que o objeto JSONObject não obtém os dados do site. Você terá que utilizar alguma biblioteca para isto, como por exemplo [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)