# Validacao via web service

Tags: php, android

preciso fazer uma validação no meu banco mysql se o e-mail que estão tentando cadastrar já existe no banco, para isto tenho meu seguinte código no web service:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    require 'connect.php';
    inReg();
}   

function inReg() {

    global $connect;
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email like '$email'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) <= 0) {
        $nomepasta = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $UploadFotos = "../../../webapps/ROOT/imagens/".$nomepasta;
        //$UploadFotos = "UploadFotos/".$nomepasta;

        if (!file_exists($UploadFotos)) {
            if (!mkdir($UploadFotos));

        }
        global $connect;

        $nome = $_POST["nome"];
        $senha = $_POST["senha"];
        $codificada = md5($senha);
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $telefone = $_POST["telefone"];

        $query = " Insert into usuario(nome, senha, email, telefone) values ('$nome','$codificada','$email','$telefone')";

        mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        mysqli_close($connect);

    } else { 
          ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
    }
} ?>
```

Não sei o que tenho que retornar caso caia na primeira condição (existe o e-mail cadastrado).
Tenho que mostrar no aplicativo android que este e-mail ja foi cadastrado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode retornar simplesmente um JSON usando o `echo` com uma mensagem específica. Exemplo:

```
} else {
    echo "{\"message\": \"Ja existe um usuario cadastrado com este email\"}";
}
```

Desta forma, basta você fazer o tratamento na sua aplicação no momento que receber a resposta do servidor, [lendo os dados do JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124861/android-ler-dados-json). Basicamente seria desta forma:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(resposta);
String message = obj.getString("message");
```