# erro ao receber JSON da url

Tags: android, json, android-studio

Seguindo a resposta dada à pergunta:

[Android: ler dados JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124861/android-ler-dados-json)

Que é exatamente o mesmo problema que o meu, cheguei na classe:

```
package com.example.carlos.radiosingular.classes;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpConnections {
    //método get
    public static String get(String urlString){
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resposta = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            resposta = buffer.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (urlConnection != null){
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                reader.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return resposta;
    }
}
```

Minha `classe` **principal**:

```
package com.example.carlos.radiosingular;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.carlos.radiosingular.classes.HttpConnections;


public class form extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form);
        String resposta = HttpConnections.get("http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php");
        Log.v("Resposta: ", resposta);
    }

}
```

Erro no meu Moto G 4 Play (Estou emulando direto no aparelho)

```
RadioSingular parou
  Abri App novamente
```

Erro no console **RUN**

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.carlos.radiosingular, PID: 21972
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.carlos.radiosingular/com.example.carlos.radiosingular.form}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native_inner(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Log.java:294)
        at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:306)
        at com.example.carlos.radiosingular.form.onCreate(form.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Erros no `Logcat` (só as ultimas linhas)

```
2018-12-13 10:36:14.455 22364-22415/? E/GmsUtils: Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
2018-12-13 10:36:29.136 4236-20786/? E/SQLiteCastStore: Skip saving CastDeviceInfo: "Dispositivo próximo" (__cast_nearby___V_d580d25c-abe2-4303-9f7d-361d2bee8a9f)
2018-12-13 10:36:34.251 393-2691/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
```

O que fazer?

O erro dá na linha:

```
    Log.v("Resposta: ", resposta);
```

Quando eu a comento, não dá erro.

Se resposta é uma string:

```
String resposta = HttpConnections.get("http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php");
```

e, comentando

```
//Log.v("Resposta: ", resposta);
```

O erro some,

Não faz sentindo para mim uma vez que rodando no navegador, a url http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php, me traz como retorno um `JSON` de forma correta:

```
[
  {"idClientesT":"1","tipo":"s","nome":"Carlos"}, 
  {"idClientesT":"2","tipo":"s","nome":"Rogério"}
]
```

Onde está o erro?

**EDIT:**

No `manifest` fiz assim:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Mesmo assim, dá o erro!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Me parece que ele não esta conseguindo printar um  JSON. Para teste faça isso: `Log.v("Resposta: ", "teste");`  para ver se dá o erro.

Comment: deu certo, não deu erro e exibiu no console V/Resposta:: teste

Comment: Bom, será que tem a ver com libração para uso da intenet? No manifest fiz assim 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> mas mesmo assim não roda

Comment: Tente assim agora `Log.v("Resposta:", resposta.toString());`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: parece que ele não está recebendo o json

Comment: Acontece que o processo é assíncrono.
Você faz a chamada nessa linha: `String resposta = HttpConnections.get("http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php");`
e não aguarda a resposta e imediatamente na linha de baixo antes da chamada retornar você já quer imprimi-la, quando a resposta ainda é nula.

Comment: hum, acho que entendi! Isso leva tempo mesmo. Você me indica algum link para eu pesquisar sobre o assunto?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229204/android-waiting-for-response-from-server

Answer (score 0):

Adicione ao build.gradle a linha no grupo dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
}
```

Adicione aos seus imports da Activity:

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
```

E chame o api desse modo:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.setTimeout(10000);

client.get("http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php" , null,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, String content) {
                   Log.v("Resposta:" content.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {
                    /* Precisa testar isso :( */
                    Log.v("Resposta:" error.toString());
                }

});
```

Comment: Transform output file D:\Trabalhos\AndroidStudio\RadioSingular\app\libs\android-async-http-1.4.4.jar does not exist.
O que pode ser será?

Comment: Baixe jar `android-async-http-1.4.4` e adicione-o dentro da pasta `libs` dentro de seu projeto. Senão houver a pasta `libs` você pode cria-la. Deve ficar assim: `C:\meuprojetoandroid\app\libs`

Comment: onSuccess e onFailure estão depreciadas e parecem com um risco por cima.

Comment: Por enquanto, esquece isso.

Comment: ok. Ficarei no aguardo!

Comment: rsrs. Aguardando o que? Você pode utilizar esses mesmos métodos sem se preocupar com o fato deles estarem depreciados ou buscar métodos semelhantes mais atualizados.

Comment: é porque não compila, dá erro.

Comment: Error: Program type already present: com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler

Comment: Por favor, olhe uma imagem que postei no final da pergunta

Comment: Não sei que erro é esse, precisaria investigar. Mas é certo que não tem a ver com a questão anterior ou com as modificações que eu sugeri que você fizesse.